# Pages 08 doesn't draw border around paragraphs correctly?

Tags: pages

If I'm using **Pages '08** and trying to draw a border around a paragraph that is inside a text box, I go to the *More* tab of the *Text Inspector* and select a solid line and full rectangle under *Border and Rules*.

[image]

The border that results, however is a top-and-bottom border, and not a full rectangle:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a known bug? If the latter, is there a workaround so I can enclose a paragraph of text in a text box with a surrounding border?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>Disclaimer: I'm using Pages '09, but I'm guessing the answer will be the same for '08.</sup>

You're seeing this because the left and right edges of the paragraph are not visible inside the text box. To work around this, you can add a small **Inset Margin** from the **Text** tab of the Text Inspector:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

OK, this is a bit kludgy, but it seems to be working (but I'd love to see a better answer!):

Instead of applying a border to a paragraph, make each paragraph its own text box and apply a border to the entire text box using the *Graphic Inspector* and setting **Stroke** to *Line*.

[image]

Comment: I don't think  your answer is kludgy at all. The text box is the object, not the paragraph.

Comment: The inspector pane implies one can add a border to a paragraph, independent of the border around the box containing the paragraph.

Comment: @DanielL They're just different "border" definitions: one meaning is to separate a paragraph from the surrounding text; the other, to draw a line around the edge of a text box. Both do different things, and your answer uses it the way it's meant to be used!

Comment: Though I do see how applying it paragraph-by-paragraph in a mass of text could count as a kludge. Yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you open a text box and click inside it as if you are writing in it, then choose style, border, line - you get a border all the way round.